# Japanese counter for exercise repetitions

Tags: counters, word-requests

Recently, I've been attempting to incorporate Japanese into my daily life more frequently. As I went through my morning exercises, I realized that I wasn't sure if simply counting 一,二,三... was correct, or if there was a specific counter for exercise repetitions (one pushup, two pushups, etc.). In looking around, the closest I've been able to find have been 度,回, and of course, つ. Does anyone know which is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about how to count when during the exercise, I would that saying

> 一｛いち｝、二｛に｝、三｛さん｝...

Is perfectly okay. I also found some evidence of [people counting in english](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0o_vExY1_Y). If you to say something along the lines of "Today I did ten pushups", then I would use 回{かい} that will indicate the number of repetitions of a given exercise. Example [here](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2134682714158177601). I would not use 度｛ど｝ in this context, because it has a meaning of occurrence rather than repetition.

Finally, if you want to count exercises as in "In my routine, the first exercise is pushups, the second is squats..." I would use

> 一｛ひと｝つ目｛め｝、二｛ふた｝つ目｛め｝

Where 目 is used to change the counter to an ordinal.